# How to compare strings in a list using python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
CommitId    RefactoringType Detail
0   d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8    Pull Up Attribute   blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...
1   d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8    Pull Up Attribute   blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...
2   d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8    Pull Up Attribute   blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...
3   4bb968a47ce00279d6051df95bd782650700179e    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...
4   c3d7ec38417ecff03d1cd3be0163e6ce07578eb3    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...
5   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
6   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
7   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
8   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
```

I readed the column CommitId  and I puted it into a list .Now I need to comapre the CommitId values if they are equals I extract all the lines and I put it into other dataframe so this is the output I need :

```
dataframe1:


0   d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8    Pull Up Attribute   blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...
1   d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8    Pull Up Attribute   blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...
2   d38f7b334856ed4007fb3ec0f8a5f7499ee2f2b8    Pull Up Attribute   blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl..

dataframe2:


3   4bb968a47ce00279d6051df95bd782650700179e    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...

dataframe3:

4   c3d7ec38417ecff03d1cd3be0163e6ce07578eb3    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Pl...

dataframe4:

5   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
6   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
7   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
8   00568c9886e739d6b5dd61b4a4326d598552fb6f    Extract Method  blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block
```

this is my code:

```
list=[]
for elm in df['CommitId']:
   list.append(elm)
   print(list)

length = len(list) 
for i in range(length):
    if()
```

the problem is in if() I did not find a way to compare CommitId and extract all lines .when I try to compare list[i] and list[i+1] it's not working

Comment: What about the last 4 rows? Are those also to be extracted? Into the same result or a new DataFrame? Please clarify.

Comment: yess they are also to be extracted to a new DataFrame.So I should have 4 dataframes

Comment: You should use a dictionnary with commitid as keys

Comment: I think you want `dicts = {key: d for key, d in df.groupby('CommitId')}`

Comment: you should try to extract line per line while you're comparing strings. It's cleaner and controlled.

Comment: @Kenry Sanchez this is the problem I could not comparing strings in the list .It's not working

Comment: @ cs95 I want just to extract into a new dataframe lines which have the same  CommitId without chaging any thing !

Comment: I edit my problem and I specified the output that I need and thanks for help !

Comment: The code I gave you extracts it into a dictionary of DataFrames indexed by the unique commit ID. You will have a dict with 4 entries. Do what you want with it.

Comment: Well, some many guys here are right. It's more easy grouping the table.

Comment: the solution proposed by @cs95 is the best it's working now thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.
You can create a DataFrameGroupBy iterable object with this command:

group = your_dataframe.groupby(['CommitId'])

that groups equal values in column CommitId and then you can create multiple dataframes in a for loop with the exec command:

```
for index,values in enumerate(group):
    exec(f'dataframe_{index+1} = pd.DataFrame(values[1])')
```

I used `enumerate` to obtain the indeces and values ​​simultaneously from the groupby iterator object and `index+1` to start from dataframe_1 variable.